# problem with cookies and jwt with node and express

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, mern

i'm currently trying to make a fullstack website using MERN stack , i wanted to use jwt with refreshToken and accessToken for the authentication of my website .
i use res.cookie to store the refreshToken  in the cookie after loging in , and i use a get request "refresh" to retrieve the refreshToken  from the cookie using req.cookies, whenever i make the login request from postman and then make the refresh request i correctly get the value of my new refreshToken. But when i make the login request from my react frontend (when i click on login) and then make the refresh request i don't get the value of my new refreshToken as i should, (even though i made sure that the new version was correctly stored in cookies of the response using dev tools )

in the beggining i thought that the res.cookie didn't work when i make the request using my fronted but this suspicion did vanish when i saw that the cookie was correctly set in the dev tools of my browser (i tried using mutliple browsers but it didn't work neither) . i've read that it may be related to my browser's cache and it didn't work even after i cleared it

here's the auth and refresh requests :

/////////////    AUTH REQUEST

```
router.post('/login',async (req,res)=>{

    const {username,password} = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({username:username});

    if (!user) return res.status(404).json({error:'there is no user with this username !'});

    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password);
    if(!match) return res.status(403).json({error:'invalid username or password '});

    
    const accessToken = jwt.sign({username:user.username},process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,{expiresIn:'900s'});
    const refreshToken = jwt.sign({username:user.username},process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,{expiresIn:'1d'});

    user.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    await user.save();

    
    res.cookie('refresh',user.refreshToken,{httpOnly:true,maxAge:1000*3600*24,domain:'localhost',path:'/'});

    res.json({accessToken:accessToken,username:user.username,id:user._id});
});
```

////////    REFRESH REQUEST

```
router.get('/',async(req,res)=>{

    const cookies = req.cookies;
    if(!cookies?.refresh) return res.json('no cookies');

    res.json({refreshToken:cookies.refresh});
});
```

Comment: Please add some code snippet that will be helpful to reply

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.